# autoit - last line in text file not being remvoed with _ArrayDelete

Tags: autoit

What this is supposed to do is remove the a string that matches in a text file. I run this through a For loop and work's fine until it gets to the last line. Where there is only one line left in the text file it will not delete it.

Any ideas?

My code is as follows.

```
$file = "lines.txt"
FileOpen($file, 0)

For $i = 1 to _FileCountLines($file)
$line = FileReadLine($file, $i)

Func _DeleteArrayElementWithStringInstr ( $_Array, $_String )
Local $_Item
For $_Element In $_Array
    If StringInStr ( $_Element, $_String ) <> 0 Then
        _ArrayDelete ( $_Array, $_Item )
    Else
        $_Item+=1
    EndIf
Next
Return ( $_Array )
EndFunc ;==> _DeleteArrayElementWithStringInstr ( )

Global $_Array
_FileReadToArray ( 'lines.txt', $_Array )
$_Array = _DeleteArrayElementWithStringInstr ( $_Array, $line )
_FileWriteFromArray ( 'lines.txt', $_Array, 1 )
Exit
```

lines.txt simple contains

```
test@example.com
email@example.com
hello@example.com
```

Comment: How does lines.txt look like and what is in $line?

If you put ConsoleWrite($Item) after line 3, is the last line printed?

Comment: Works for me. Please provide a testable example.

Comment: added more to my code, sorry didn't realize that I didn't add the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that your file actually contains more than three lines, but the last line(s) may be empty. Therefore you should use a for loop and check if your last element equals an empty string. If so call _ArrayDelete.